# How to use Calculator on MacOS Catalina

Tags: catalina

I can't figure how to use Calculator in Catalina. Screenshot is where I keyed in 4 * 3 and an Enter, I get output of 3 instead of 12 and neither can I read what I keyed in nor scroll arrow-up for any previous result.  I thought I had some sort of mental blockage so I actually read the [Calculator User Guide for Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/guide/calculator/welcome/mac) - still didn't find what I did wrong with the Calculator. I regret upgrading to Catalina, everything is just a disaster. I have to use Terminal for basic calculation, if someone can show me how to use Calculator like we used to on the Dashboard or on normal physical calculator...

[image: Key in 4 * 3 and Enter]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## RPN Mode

The problem most probably stems from the calculator being in the [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) (RPN) mode. Things should go back to normal if you simply turn the RPN mode off by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.